# WooThemes + Custom Sidebars and Archive Template Issue

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Curious if anyone can help me on this. I am using WooThemes to create this site.

IN SHORT:
- Wordpress + Woo Themes
- Custom Post Types + Taxonomies
- Woo Themes Sidebars

Currently I have a CPT, "Broadcast", which has a taxonomy of "Broadcast_Categories".
I add a new Broadcast 'item', and on the left I have custom sidebar using WooThemes Sidebar manager for the 'template'.

When I FILTER down from the Broadcast_categories, from my understanding I get "taxonomy" page. 
But I can't seem to display my custom sidebars on this page.

So my thought was to use a basic Wordpress 'page' and apply a 'template' to it. But I can't seem to link the two together.

I know this might be confusing, so here is a 'sample-link'.
http://tech.stickystudios.ca/products/broadcast/

And if you click on the left, one of the categories, you notice that the sidebar disapears and the background changes b/c it's not using the right 'template'.

Any thoughts or direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WooThemes came out with a new Sidebar Manager that solved this problem!